# How to automate/integrate web apps

Tags: python, automation

I understand my question is somewhat broad but I need broad answers.

I have been tasked to automate transfer of information between some web apps that the company uses (hackpad, pipedrive, stripe, google sheets, gmail etc.). Could some one please give me high level idea on how to go about this?

Google search throws up things like Google app script. But I want a broad idea on building automation solutions (maybe using python) for tasks like these. References to literature are also welcome.

Comment: *"I understand my question is somewhat broad but I need broad answers"* - then you will understand when it is VTC as... too broad.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not surprised by the VTC but I was hoping some one would be kind enough to point me in the right direction. I am just starting off as an intern.

Comment: Note that requests for off-site resources are also off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All of the products you mentioned have a developer api and as such can be integrated via their respective APIs. Outside of that because of the generality of your questions I can't provide much detail or help.

I can share an example of how I integrated two CRM apps (in this case Infusion and Salesforce).

The basic gist is that you need a central application under your control to do the coordination. That application is responsible for integrating with each of your client applications, retrieving their data, transforming it, and processing it for use by other applications.

For any application I integrated with, I created an inbound and outbound adapter so the information wouldn't be muddled.

If available, you could use [webhooks](http://webhooks.us/) from the end applications to send a notification to your central app when something has changed.

The most important aspect is to not let the details of the endpoint applications bleed into the controller app. Create a "canonical" data structure that is the "lingua franca" between the other nodes in your application. This way when you switch from one provider to another, you don't have to deal with the differences in their message structure, you just have to map the new data to your canonical.

Comment: Where should this controller app reside?